# How to calculate this double limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (+\infty, +\infty)} (1 + \frac{1}{xy})^{x\sin y}$

The solution provided shows that:

$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (+\infty, +\infty)} (1 + \frac{1}{xy})^{x\sin y} = \lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (+\infty, +\infty)} (1 + \frac{1}{xy})^{x\sin y} = \lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (+\infty, +\infty)} (1 + \frac{1}{xy})^{xy \frac{\sin y}{y}} = \lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (+\infty, +\infty)} ((1 + \frac{1}{xy})^{xy })^{\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}} = e^0 = 1$

How did the last step come across? Since quatratic limits is not necessarily equal to double limits?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a rigorous argument to me; you are right to be concerned/confused. I'm having trouble coming up with a rigorous argument though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like all these limit operators carried everywhere.

I would go considering only the expansion of $\ln(1+\frac 1{xy})\sim \frac 1{xy}$ since $xy\to +\infty$.

$\big(1+\frac 1{xy}\big)^{x\sin(y)}=\exp\bigg(x\sin(y)\ln(1+\frac 1{xy})\bigg)=\exp\bigg(x\sin(y)\big(\frac 1{xy}+o(\frac 1{xy})\big)\bigg)=\exp\big(\frac{\sin(y)}{y}+o(\frac 1y)\big)\to e^0=1$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This argument is fine.  I gather you're concerned about the statement $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}\left(1+\frac1{xy}\right)^{xy}=e,$$ byt just write $z=xy$.  Surely, as $(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)$ we have $z\to\infty$ so it's jus $$\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1z\right)^z=e.$$

We have the same expression, $xy$, in both places, so there's no problem.  You're right to be concerned, though. If we had something like $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}\left(1+\frac1{xy}\right)^{y}$$ the limit wouldn't exist.